# Variable used by function before being initialized

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm having trouble changing 'cityName' in the function below

```
private func processResponse(withPlacemarks placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) {
@Binding var cityName:String?

if let error = error {
    print("Unable to Reverse Geocode Location (\(error))")
} else {
    if let placemarks = placemarks, let placemark = placemarks.first {
        cityName = placemark.locality
    } else {
        print("No matching address found")
    }
} }
```

The error that it throws on `cityName = placemark.locality` is `Variable '_cityName' used by function definition before being initialized`. I've initialized cityName in another file called ContentView.swift with `@State var cityName:String = ""`

I'm entirely new at Swift so any help would be appreciated.

***EDIT:*** Here's more code for context

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var cityName:String = ""
    @State var temp:Double = 0
    @State var condition:String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            UserLocatonButtonView()
                
            //Text view
            weatherInfo(cityName: $cityName, temp: $temp, condition: $condition)
            //Text("Temperature: \(temp), Condition: \(condition)")
        }
    }
}


struct weatherInfo: View {
    @Binding var cityName: String
    @Binding var temp: Double
    @Binding var condition: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(self.$cityName.wrappedValue.capitalized)
                .padding()
                .font(.title)
            Text(String(format: "%.1f *C", $temp.wrappedValue))
                .padding()
                .font(.title)
            Text($condition.wrappedValue)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 400)
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.1))
    }
}
```

UserLocationManager.swift (processResponse is at the bottom of this file)

```
import CoreLocation
import CoreLocationUI
import SwiftUI

struct UserLocatonButtonView: View {
    @StateObject private var locationManager = UserLocationManager()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let location = locationManager.location {
                Text("Your location: \(location.coordinate.latitude), \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
            }

            LocationButton(.currentLocation) {
                locationManager.requestAllowOnceLocationPermission()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)
            .symbolVariant(.fill)
            .tint(Color.black.opacity(0.3))
        }
    }
}

final class UserLocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    @Published var location = CLLocation()
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    // Request location once
    func requestAllowOnceLocationPermission() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // if there are not locations
        guard let latestLocation = locations.last else {
            // show an error
            return
        }
        // If location is updated
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
            
            self.location = CLLocation(latitude: latestLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)
            //self.location = latestLocation.coordinate
            print("\(latestLocation.coordinate.latitude), \(latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
            
            geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(self.location) { (placemarks, error) in
                processResponse(withPlacemarks: placemarks, error: error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("\(self.location.coordinate.latitude), \(self.location.coordinate.longitude)")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}

/************
 *
 * Helper function for coverting coordinates to city location
 *
 ************/
private func processResponse(withPlacemarks placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) {
    @Binding var cityName: String

    if let error = error {
        print("Unable to Reverse Geocode Location (\(error))")
        //locationLabel.text = "Unable to Find Address for Location"

    } else {
        if let placemarks = placemarks, let placemark = placemarks.first {
            //locationLabel.text = placemark.compactAddress
            cityName = placemark.locality!
        } else {
            print("No matching address found")
            //locationLabel.text = "No Matching Addresses Found"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have a `@Binding` *inside* a function, so that points to something else going wrong here. `@Binding` should be defined at the top level of a `View`.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to how I would modify a StateObject outside of a View?

Comment: Unfortunately, this needs more context. Can you provide a [mre]? What is the `StateObject`? Your question never refers to that at all.

Comment: I just added more code for context

Comment: @jnpdx is the code clear enough?

Comment: It is -- not enough time to answer right now, but maybe someone else will grab it. If not, I can tomorrow.

Comment: you could try replacing `@Binding var cityName: String` in `processResponse`, with a 
`@Published var cityName: String` in `UserLocationManager`, and use that to access `cityName` where you need it.

Comment: @drunkenspider I provided an answer -- did it answer your question? If not, is there a way I could improve it?

Comment: @jnpdx I ended up using a similar solution to the second suggestion you had. I made the model an ObservedObject and all the variables inside were Published.

Comment: StackOverflow etiquette is generally to accept and or upvote an answer that is correct and or helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a big refactor, the quickest changes may be explicitly passing the `Binding` to `cityName` through the views and to the `UserLocationManager`. That might look like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cityName:String = ""
    @State var temp:Double = 0
    @State var condition:String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            UserLocatonButtonView(cityName: $cityName)
            WeatherInfo(cityName: $cityName, temp: $temp, condition: $condition)
        }
    }
}


struct WeatherInfo: View {
    @Binding var cityName: String
    @Binding var temp: Double
    @Binding var condition: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(cityName.capitalized)
                .padding()
                .font(.title)
            Text(String(format: "%.1f *C", temp))
                .padding()
                .font(.title)
            Text(condition)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 400)
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.1))
    }
}


struct UserLocatonButtonView: View {
    @StateObject private var locationManager : UserLocationManager
    
    init(cityName: Binding<String>) {
        _locationManager = StateObject(wrappedValue: UserLocationManager(cityName: cityName))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let location = locationManager.location {
                Text("Your location: \(location.coordinate.latitude), \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
            }

            LocationButton(.currentLocation) {
                locationManager.requestAllowOnceLocationPermission()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)
            .symbolVariant(.fill)
            .tint(Color.black.opacity(0.3))
        }
    }
}

final class UserLocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var cityName : Binding<String>
    @Published var location = CLLocation()
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    init(cityName: Binding<String>) {
        self.cityName = cityName
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    // Request location once
    func requestAllowOnceLocationPermission() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // if there are not locations
        guard let latestLocation = locations.last else {
            // show an error
            return
        }
        // If location is updated
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
            
            self.location = CLLocation(latitude: latestLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)
            //self.location = latestLocation.coordinate
            print("\(latestLocation.coordinate.latitude), \(latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
            
            geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(self.location) { (placemarks, error) in
                self.processResponse(withPlacemarks: placemarks, error: error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("\(self.location.coordinate.latitude), \(self.location.coordinate.longitude)")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func processResponse(withPlacemarks placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Unable to Reverse Geocode Location (\(error))")
            //locationLabel.text = "Unable to Find Address for Location"

        } else {
            if let placemarks = placemarks, let placemark = placemarks.first {
                //locationLabel.text = placemark.compactAddress
                cityName.wrappedValue = placemark.locality!
            } else {
                print("No matching address found")
                //locationLabel.text = "No Matching Addresses Found"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, I think a much cleaner solution would be moving the shared state to be owned by the parent view a model and `@Published` property. Also, perhaps it's just a result of your minimal example, but you only need to use `Binding`s when you need two-way communication. So, as it stands, your `WeatherInfo` doesn't need `Binding`s at all. Once such refactor might look like this:

```
struct Model {
    var cityName : String
    var temp: Double
    var condition: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var manager = UserLocationWeatherManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            UserLocatonButtonView(manager: manager)
            WeatherInfo(cityName: manager.model.cityName,
                        temp: manager.model.temp,
                        condition: manager.model.condition)
        }
    }
}


struct WeatherInfo: View {
    var cityName: String
    var temp: Double
    var condition: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(cityName.capitalized)
                .padding()
                .font(.title)
            Text(String(format: "%.1f *C", temp))
                .padding()
                .font(.title)
            Text(condition)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 400)
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.1))
    }
}


struct UserLocatonButtonView: View {
    @ObservedObject var manager : UserLocationWeatherManager
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let location = manager.location {
                Text("Your location: \(location.coordinate.latitude), \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
            }

            LocationButton(.currentLocation) {
                manager.requestAllowOnceLocationPermission()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)
            .symbolVariant(.fill)
            .tint(Color.black.opacity(0.3))
        }
    }
}

final class UserLocationWeatherManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @Published var model = Model(cityName: "", temp: 0, condition: "")
    @Published var location = CLLocation()
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    // Request location once
    func requestAllowOnceLocationPermission() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // if there are not locations
        guard let latestLocation = locations.last else {
            // show an error
            return
        }
        // If location is updated
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
            
            self.location = CLLocation(latitude: latestLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)
            //self.location = latestLocation.coordinate
            print("\(latestLocation.coordinate.latitude), \(latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
            
            geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(self.location) { (placemarks, error) in
                self.processResponse(withPlacemarks: placemarks, error: error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("\(self.location.coordinate.latitude), \(self.location.coordinate.longitude)")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func processResponse(withPlacemarks placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Unable to Reverse Geocode Location (\(error))")
            //locationLabel.text = "Unable to Find Address for Location"

        } else {
            if let placemarks = placemarks, let placemark = placemarks.first {
                //locationLabel.text = placemark.compactAddress
                self.model.cityName = placemark.locality!
            } else {
                print("No matching address found")
                //locationLabel.text = "No Matching Addresses Found"
            }
        }
    }
}
```